# Can a single variable represent both address and value without special characters. How can this be possible?

Tags: c, string

I have a question in strings. In the given program: c is used after scanf ( which indicates address) and the same c is used after printf (which means value), then what should we consider c as a memory location or value? . Can anyone explain this in detail?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char c[50];
printf("enter the string");
scanf("%s",c);
printf("the value of string is %s",c);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The variable `c` is an array, nothing more and nothing less. It's contents is the data stored in the array. It can *decay* to a pointer to its first element (i.e. when you use `c` in the calls to `scanf` and `printf` it's actually the same as doing `&c[0]`).

Comment: It's an array (so a value) which decays to a pointer (so a memory location) when passed to those functions as an argument. If you're asking for an essay on what pointers and arrays are, that's a whole essay and probably too big for an answer here.

Comment: Garf365 my question is different

Comment: But answers of this question are same as yours. Joachim Pileborg has summarized them into its comment

Comment: Joachim and Useless thanks for responding but now also I am not getting in strings after scanf and printf how can we use the same variable. It will be really helpful if you you can explain in detail.

Comment: `scanf` reads the characters in (to the array `c`) and `printf` prints things out - we can use the same variable for different things and usually do.

Comment: Garf365 my question is not about array and pointer... My question is can a variable store both address and value within the same function?

Comment: The compiler knows.